# How to summon an immovable minecart?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have seen a few old questions but the solutions no longer work for the latest version (1.12.2).

How do I summon an immovable, invulnerable minecart?

Comment: I know nothing of minecraft commands, and idk what you are planning to accomplish, but setting the gamemode to adventure would make the minecart invulnerable. At least I would think. Depends on your scenario, but I would see that as a viable solution without using commands. It would not be immovable though.

Comment: @Kyle Rone You can't set anyone's gamemode to adventure without using commands, at least not without an NBT editor.

Comment: This is for a public server where the members are required to be in survival.

Comment: @Fabian, goes to show just how much I know about commands. I can teleport myself and thats about it haha.

Comment: @Kyle Rone And apparently you can also change your gamemode, because you didn't even think about it being a command.

Comment: lol good point :p

Answer (score 2):

Invulnerable is easy; just summon it with the `Invulnerable:1b` tag. Immovable is a bit harder, as there is no built-in way to make minecarts immobile. Probably the easiest way is to summon the minecart as a passenger of another entity which *is* immobile and cannot be seen or interacted with, such as a lingering potion cloud.

```
summon area_effect_cloud ~ ~ ~ {Duration:-1,Age:-2147483648,WaitTime:-2147483648,Passengers:[{id:"minecraft:minecart",Invulnerable:1b}]}
```

This command will summon an area effect cloud that is completely invisible and does not apply any potion effect, and which will last for six real-life years (the maximum possible without constantly running commands to renew it). Riding the AEC will be your invulnerable minecart. Because it is riding the AEC, and the AEC cannot move, the minecart will not move.

Comment: I didn't even think about passengers. But yes, it's probably a better solution than mine, more lag-friendly. Personally, I'm not a big fan of AECs, because their tags are harder to remember and to explain to people who are new to commands, but that's everyone's own decision. It doesn't change much to use an armor stand or an AEC.

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent the minecart to be pushed, but you can teleport it back immediately:

Summon an immovable, invulnerable armor stand where you want the minecart to be:

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {NoAI:1,NoGravity:1,Marker:1,Invulnerable:1,Invisible:1,Tags:[minecartTpTarget]}
```

You won't see it unless you're in spectator mode.

Then put an active repeating command block either in the spawn chunks or near the armor stand with this command in it:

```
/tp @e[tag=minecartToTp] @e[tag=minecartTpTarget]
```

Then you summon the minecart with:

```
/summon minecart ~ ~ ~ {NoAI:1,NoGravity:1,Invulnerable:1,Tags:[minecartToTp]}
```

Comment: Interestingly, this answer should still work the exact same way in 1.13, despite ~90% of all command stuff changing. At least I think it should, I'm not sure.